# Installation (startup.bat) script won't start my app, error appears

Tags: java, spring, batch-file, app-startup, startupscript

I'm trying to create .bat script that will start my Java application. Application uses a lot of the dependencies so I have to create a fat jar:

I did that by adding this dependency to my pom.xml:

**pom.xml**

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
    
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>my.path.MicroserviceApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
    
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

After that I executed maven clean install which created two jar files in my target folder. One 'normal' jar and one fat jar. I used path to that fat jar and I tried to run it via my script but I got error.

**Bat Script:**

```
echo off

set "JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_291"
set "PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_291/bin;%PATH%"
set "MICRO_HTTP=C:/Users/just.quest/workspace/application_parent/MicroserviceApp"

set "CLASSPATH=%MICRO_HTTP%/target/MicroserviceApp-20.14.1-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

java -jar %CLASSPATH%

pause
```

And error that I'm getting:

**Error Log from command prompt:**

```
        }{
  "timestamp" : "2021-11-22T09:40:52.563Z",
  "level" : "ERROR",
  "thread" : "main",
  "logger" : "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication",
  "message" : "Application run failed",
  "context" : "default",
  "exception" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.\r\n\tat org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:470)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:180)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:434)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:879)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)"
}{
  "timestamp" : "2021-11-22T09:40:52.565Z",
  "level" : "DEBUG",
  "thread" : "main",
  "logger" : "org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext",
  "message" : "Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6fa51cd4, started on Mon Nov 22 10:40:52 CET 2021",
  "context" : "default"
}Press any key to continue . . .
```

So as you can see, it seems there is some problem with the *"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories."*

I've tried to google this but I couldn't find anything useful and I've already spent too much time on this so I'm out of options. I hope someone knows how can I start application from my command prompt.

**When I start application from Eclipse, everything works fine. This error is present only when I use my .bat script.**

Comment: Ditch the assembly plugin, add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` which already creates a fat runnable jar. You are working around/against the framework instead of using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks *M. Deinum*, that fixed my problem:

I had to replace **maven-assembly-plugin** with the:

```
      <build>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                         <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                 </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      </build>
```